# How to have Drush installed without Drupal container

Tags: php, docker, drupal, dependency-management, drush

I would like to have Drush in my Docker but without a Drupal container.
I have nginx, php and mysql as containers and I wonder if I can install Drush in my php container like a module for exemple. 
Because I use this as web developpement environnement I don't want to be more specific with Docker, with this I can install any CMS or else web project.

Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Try make your own container including in your dockerfile:

```
RUN export COMPOSER_HOME=/usr/local/composer && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    composer global require drush/drush:6.5.0 && \
    composer global install && \
    ln -s /usr/local/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
```

You can use the yoshz image also (includes apache):

https://github.com/yoshz/docker-php